# ng-show directive not working properly in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to assign parameter values passed from an function to ng-show but getting nowhere with it...what i am trying to do is call the function on click inside the textbox and assign the value for ng-show...The function is getting called but value is not getting assigned...

```
<span ng-show="show.error"> <font color="red">Error</font> </span>
<input type="text" ng-model="template.name" ng-click="checkerrorexist(this)"></td>


  $scope.checkerrorexist = function(scope){

        $scope.apply(function() {
               $scope.show.error=true;
            })

    };
```

I dont know where i am going wrong...can someone help plz...

Comment: Remove the `$scope.$apply()` and make sure you have `$scope.error = {error: false};` when you initialize your controller.

Comment: Have tried it as well...still not working

Comment: Then it something else that is not included in your post. Consider creating a fiddle that demonstrates the problem or at least provide an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is more or less correct, but without seeing the larger scope of your app I cant tell what may be the larger potential problem. Anyways debugging this piece of code.

HTML:

```
<span ng-show="show.error"> <font color="red">Error</font> </span>
<input type="text" ng-model="template.name" ng-click="checkerrorexist()"></td>
```

Controller Code:

```
  $scope.show = { error: false };
  $scope.checkerrorexist = function(){
       $scope.show.error = true;
  };
```

$scope.$apply() is not needed as when angular updates/changes pieces of the scope is automatically fires a digest cycle - which is what the $apply does for us.